# How do I get the full file name for failed .NET tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I've never used dotnet/.NET for unit tests before so I'm very new to how it all works. I'm starting work on an existing project with many unit tests already createdin C# and Lua, and after running those existing tests, it shows that 454 have passed and 2 have failed, but I can't seem to find out which tests specifically failed.

When I run dotnet test through Windows Powershell, I get the following output:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:19.7411114]     tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(testFile: "C:\\Users\\ccort\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Epic stuff "...) [FAIL]
  X tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(testFile: "C:\\Users\\ccort\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Epic stuff "...) [55ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 0
Actual:   4
  Stack Trace:
     at tests.ScriptedTests.AssertEqual(Int32 v1, Int32 v2) in C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff for my job\epictourneyserver\tests\ScriptedTests.cs:line 26
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Interop.MethodMemberDescriptor.Execute(Script script, Object obj, ScriptExecutionContext context, CallbackArguments args)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Interop.FunctionMemberDescriptorBase.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<GetCallback>b__0(ScriptExecutionContext c, CallbackArguments a)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.CallbackFunction.Invoke(ScriptExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 args, Boolean isMethodCall)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Internal_ExecCall(Int32 argsCount, Int32 instructionPtr, CallbackFunction handler, CallbackFunction continuation, Boolean thisCall, String debugText, DynValue unwindHandler)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Processing_Loop(Int32 instructionPtr)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Call(DynValue function, DynValue[] args)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script.Call(DynValue function)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script.DoString(String code, Table globalContext, String codeFriendlyName)
   at tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(String testFile) in C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff for my job\epictourneyserver\tests\ScriptedTests.cs:line 138
[xUnit.net 00:00:23.2775868]     tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(testFile: "C:\\Users\\ccort\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Epic stuff "...) [FAIL]
  X tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(testFile: "C:\\Users\\ccort\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Epic stuff "...) [83ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 1
Actual:   0
  Stack Trace:
     at tests.ScriptedTests.AssertEqual(Int32 v1, Int32 v2) in C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff for my job\epictourneyserver\tests\ScriptedTests.cs:line 26
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Interop.MethodMemberDescriptor.Execute(Script script, Object obj, ScriptExecutionContext context, CallbackArguments args)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Interop.FunctionMemberDescriptorBase.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<GetCallback>b__0(ScriptExecutionContext c, CallbackArguments a)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Internal_ExecCall(Int32 argsCount, Int32 instructionPtr, CallbackFunction handler, CallbackFunction continuation, Boolean thisCall, String debugText, DynValue unwindHandler)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Processing_Loop(Int32 instructionPtr)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Execution.VM.Processor.Call(DynValue function, DynValue[] args)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script.Call(DynValue function)
   at MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script.DoString(String code, Table globalContext, String codeFriendlyName)
   at tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest(String testFile) in C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff for my job\epictourneyserver\tests\ScriptedTests.cs:line 138

Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 456
     Passed: 454
     Failed: 2
 Total time: 27.1261 Seconds

---------------------------------
```

Notice how it lists the failed file name as "C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff "..., which is quite useless when it comes to looking for the file in my computer. Using Visual Studio's Test Explorer gives the same exact issue, only showing the beginning of the failed test's file path rather than the entire file path or even just the file's name.

How can I find the exact file name or full file path of tests that fail? I'm looking for the full string parameter "testFile", which gets passed to the method ScriptedTests.RunTest().

Comment: It's quite uncommon to have spaces in directory names for project directories, but you do. The full path to your file is `C:\Users\ccort\OneDrive\Documents\Epic stuff for my job\epictourneyserver\tests\ScriptedTests.cs`. I bet that file exists.

Comment: ScriptedTests.cs runs code contained in many different files, so even though ScriptedTests.cs is involved in the testing process, it doesn't actually contain the test code that's failing or passing. This is line 138 of ScriptedTests.cs, the line mentioned in the stack trace:

try
            {
                var code = File.ReadAllText(testFile);
                script.DoString(code);
            }

And there are many different testFiles being passed there, and I don't know which are failing. ScriptedTests.cs just contains the RunTest method which acts on a passed filename.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Got it now. Try adding a `Console.WriteLine` (or `Debug.WriteLine`) in `tests.ScriptedTests.RunTest`. This output is visible in the test explorer or the console.